# passing array (not vector) to function

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to do this

```
void DoSomething (int arr[])
{
// do something
}
```

but instead of `arr[]` it's `std::array`

```
void DoSomething (std::array <int> arr) // <--- incorrect way to declare an array
{
// do something
}
```

Using `std::vector` instead of `std::array` works, but I expect a workaround with `std::array`, since `arr[]` works just fine.

This works too

```
const int arrSize;
void DoSomething (std::array <int,arrSize> arr)
{
// do something
}
```

but again, I expect a way to do this without any extra declarations.

Comment: Show a [mcve], how you are going to call the function and pass arguments.

Comment: `void DoSomething (int arr[])` ends up passing a pointer and loses all size info so DoSomething does not know how many elements to operate on.

Comment: Pass a pointer to the first slot, then also pass the capacity of the array.  When passing an array to a function, the capacity property is lost.

Comment: `std::array` is an array of a fixed size that _must_ be specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::array` is a template. If you want to accept a `std::array` of any size, your function will have to become a template as well, eg:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
void DoSomething (std::array<int, N> arr)
{
    // do something
}
```

The compiler can then deduce `N` for you, based on whatever `std::array` you pass in.

Comment: Consider passing the array by (const) reference `(const) std::array<int,N>& arr` to avoid copying the array